# Sliding a large image within UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a large image with 1000 px width. I want to display the image in original size and I want it to automatically scroll from right to left in an animation. For example in IPhone 6 it should display the 375 px first, then should move to the left till the all parts of photo is displayed in time. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// You have to put the imageView inside a UIScrollView
// Set the duration you want for your animation
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5f animations:^{
    //Code for animation
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(imageView.frame.size.width - scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.contentOffset.y) animated:NO];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //Code after the animation is completed
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically scroll UIScrollView with setContentOffset function. For example:

```
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: scrollView.frame.width - imageView.frame.width, y: 0), animated: true)
```

You can also set the contentOffset property within UIView.animateWithDuration block for more controlled animation.